# Is it possible to differenciate proxy error from endpoint error with php curl

Tags: php, curl, proxy, http-request

little curl question ^^

You have:

- a site web (endpoint.com/request.php)
- a proxy server (proxy.com:8080)

Is it possible when sending requests through proxy with php_curl to remote web site (ex: an API) to differentiate cases when the proxy part failed (ex: proxy down, bad auth, timeout ...)  from when the remote web site fails (ex: 404, site down, bad auth, timeout ...)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [PHP Curl documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and/or the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

It looks like the only proxy-specific error code is `(CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY) 5`

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like a good lead... but I wonder what happens in case of proxy timeout, proxy bad auth... => so much cases to test...

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the response result of curl_exec($curl) and try to display the error using

```php
if (!$response) {
    echo "cURL error number:" .curl_errno($curl)."\t";
    echo "cURL error:" . curl_error($curl)."\n";
}
```